# How to customize side menu animation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I´m developing an Ionic 4 aplication and I want to usea a custom side menu animation like this:

[image]

but Ionic only have 3 options: push, overlay and reveal.

I already have my 3dmenu.ts file but I don´t no how to inject it to use It with the Ion-menu componet like the other 3 options, could some one give a hint about how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I finally can do it, Using workaruond than I found here [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15789). The trick is extend the menu controller class to create a new method registerAnimation:

Step 1: Create a new ts file (extended.ts or the name than you want) and put this code inside:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AnimationBuilder } from '@ionic/core';

function proxyMethod(ctrlName: string, doc: Document, methodName: string, ...args: any[]) {
    const controller = ensureElementInBody(ctrlName, doc);
    return controller.componentOnReady()
        .then(() => (controller as any)[methodName].apply(controller, args));
}

function ensureElementInBody(elementName: string, doc: Document) {
    let element = doc.querySelector(elementName);
    if (!element) {
        element = doc.createElement(elementName);
        doc.body.appendChild(element);
    }
    return element as HTMLStencilElement;
}

const CTRL = 'ion-menu-controller';
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})

export class EloMenuController extends MenuController {

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {
        super(document)
    }

    /**
    * Registers a new animation that can be used with any `ion-menu` by
    * passing the name of the animation in its `type` property.
    *
    * @param name The name of the animation to register.
    * @param animation The animation function to register.
    */
    registerAnimation(name: string, animation: AnimationBuilder) {
        return proxyMethod(CTRL, this.document, 'registerAnimation', name, animation);
    }
}
```

Step 2: Create a new ts file with the animation, in my case I use this:

```
import { Animation, MenuI } from '@ionic/core';

export function menu3D (AnimationC: Animation, baseEl: HTMLElement, menu: MenuI):     
Promise<Animation> {        

    let contentOpenedX: string;
    let menuClosedX: string;
    const width = menu.width;
    const baseAnimation = new AnimationC();

    if (menu.isEndSide) {
        contentOpenedX = -width + 'px';
        menuClosedX = width + 'px';
    } 
    else {
        contentOpenedX = width + 'px';
        menuClosedX = -width + 'px';
    }

    const menuAnimation = new AnimationC()
        .addElement(menu.menuInnerEl)
        .fromTo('z-index', '0', '0')
        .fromTo('translateX', menuClosedX, '0px');

   const contentAnimation = new AnimationC()
       .addElement(menu.contentEl)
       .fromTo('translateX', '0px', contentOpenedX)
       .fromTo('scale', '1', '0.7');

   const backdropAnimation = new AnimationC()
       .addElement(menu.backdropEl)
       .fromTo('opacity', 0.01, 0.32);

   return Promise.resolve(baseAnimation
       .addElement(baseEl)
       .easing('cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')
       .easingReverse('cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.6, 1)')
       .duration(300)
       .add(contentAnimation)
       .add(menuAnimation)
       .add(backdropAnimation));
};
```

Step 3: import in your app.component.ts the extended class and the animation and register your animation to be able to use it:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Extend } from './animations/extend
import { menu3D } from './animations/menu3D';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() name: string;

    constructor(
        private menu: Extend
    ) {
        this.menu.registerAnimation('menu3d', menu3D);
    }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Step 4: configure the type to your ion-menu component

```
<ion-menu side="start" type="menu3d" style="z-index: 10;">
    ........
</ion-menu>
```

Step 5: Don't forget to thanks to svallory from github and Enjoy it :-)

I don´t konw if it this the best way to do it but its the only way than I found after 5 days searching, I hope this helps other and if anyone can improve this feel free to comment :-)

Comment: I tried your method but not able to proceed because the VScode complain that "Cannot find name 'HTMLStencilElement'"  and also constructor does not expect "document" parameter in first file. I think the reason is because I am using Ionic 5. Do you have solution for that?